# Saving a blob using FileSaver.js

Tags: javascript, filesaver.js

I use [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) to save a blob containing some binary data. I construct the blob from ArrayBuffer like this:

```
saveAs(new Blob([arr], {type: "application/octet-stream"}), '_test.data');
```

Now the problem is that the resulting file is all zeroes. When I print the content of the ArrayBuffer, the bytes are just OK, it's not an "all-zero" array. Clearly the construction of the blob must be wrong in some way. But according to the documentation, this should be the way to do it. That is, it should be able to accept ArrayBuffer, which should be packed within another array (hence the square brackets) and octet-stream type should stand for binary data. So what am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: Any update on this?

Answer (score 2):

I dont know how you are creating your binary array because it is working here. You can compare with following code Or provide your code so that we can check

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Web Page Design</title>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/1.3.8/FileSaver.min.js">
  </script>
  <script>
    document.write("Hello, Coding Ground!");
    var str = "Hello";
    var bytes = []; // char codes
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; ++i) {
      var code = str.charCodeAt(i);
      bytes = bytes.concat([code]);

    }
    var blob = new Blob(bytes, {
      type: "application/octet-stream"
    });
    saveAs(blob, "_data.data");
  </script>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I said ArrayBuffer, not Array. Anyway, I will try whether it works with a simple Array to isolate the problem.

Comment: OK, that seems to be the problem. When I replace ArrayBuffer with Array, it works. I will do a bit more testing and conclude it somehow. Thanks...